# Selecting attributes that contain "%"-symbol in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes, select-by-attribute

I have a Text field and it contains values that have a "%"-symbol and "°"-symbol.
 Example:

```
1.2% 3.2° 2.3% -1.2°
```

I don't know how to select just the values that have the "%"-symbol because Field Calculator thinks its a Wild Card. Any ideas?

Comment: Which software is that?

Comment: In QGIS try this `"field name"  ~ '%'`

Comment: ArcGIS 10.8. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the last answer to [How do I escape a percentage sign in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191449/how-do-i-escape-a-percentage-sign-in-t-sql) this is working with my data that is in a file geodatabase:

```
textfield LIKE '%|%%' ESCAPE '|'
```

The query might be different depending on your data source.

You can use python with da.SearchCursor to look for %-signs and select by objectid of the rows matching:

```
import arcpy
layer = 'ak_riks'
field_to_search_in = 'textfield'
search_for = '%'

oidfield = arcpy.Describe(layer).OIDFieldName
oids_to_select = tuple([oid for oid, phrase in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, ['OID@', field_to_search_in]) if search_for in phrase])

sql = """{0} IN{1}""".format(oidfield, oids_to_select)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=layer, where_clause=sql)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bera. It worked for me. Super.

Comment: Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox